# Connect to a Docker container from an application hosted on Azure Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks

***Scenario***:

I'm writing some *E2e tests* for an application hosted on an *`Azure Kubernetes Cluster`*. This application needs to access a database running locally in a Docker container. As a test framework, I'm using ***TestContainers***.

***Infrastructure Info***:

The Docker container runs in an Azure VM and that is in the same VNet of the K8s cluster. I'm pretty sure because both application (docker and pod) can access an Azure VM server which is in the same network.
The network plugin type of the K8s cluster is *`kubenet`*.

In order to spawn docker container in the same VNet, I'm using the `CNM plugin` provided by the *Azure Container Networking team*.

So, I create a *docker network* with `azure-vnet driver`

> docker network create --driver=azure-vnet --ipam-driver=azure-vnet
> --subnet=[mySubnetInCIDRformat] azurevnet

and I run the sql-container in that network.

```
var sqlContainer= new ContainerBuilder()
    .WithName(hostname)
    .WithExposedPort(1433)
    .WithNetwork("azurevnet")
    .WithImage(SqlServerImage)
    .WithEnvironment(AcceptEulaEnvVarName, Yes)
    .WithEnvironment(SaPasswordEnvVarName, sqlSaPassword)
.Build();

await sqlContainer.StartAsync();
```

***Problem***:

The pod cannot access the database. Another docker container, running on the same host of the SqlContainer, is able to connect so the database is up and running.

I had a wrong assumption that since both pod and container are in the same network, the connection was successful but it seems not the case.

The connection string is built with this code snippet:

```
ServerName = $@"{sqlContainer.IpAddress}\SQLEXPRESS";
ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionString(new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    UserID = SqlUsername,
    DataSource = ServerName,
    Password = Credentials.Password
}
.ToString());
```

***Question***:

Now I come to the question which, I know:), is quite generic and I'm sorry about that but:

is there a way to connect from a pod to a docker container if the pod runs on an Azure K8s cluster and the container in an Azure VM if they are in the same Azure VNet? Am I missing something or some configuration or that is not possible at all because of the networking stack?

***EDIT***: An idea could be to deploy the Sql container as an *Azure Container Instance*. Maybe that could fix all my issue but I still want to investigate anyway if I can achieve my goal because I wouldn't throw what I've now away and maybe the issue is just a missed configuration:)

Comment: I am little confused here, I mean why aren't you attaching your ACR to the AKS cluster? there is an option to attach your AKS to the ACR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: @Arko Thanks for joining the post. currently my docker images are not in an Azure Container Registry but they are locally. Once I've a working solution I'll migrate them to an ACR and implement a proper Azure pipeline for that but for now I want just to check that the solution I'm working on is feasible.

Comment: @Arko Anyway you made me think that maybe I could use Azure Container Instance and avoid the complexity of the network because I could deploy the container directly in the VNet without relying on additional network plugin.